# Is there any Office 365 SDK for Java?

Tags: ms-office, preview

The purpose is to use it from web server applications. I've seen Office 365 SDK for Android, that basically is Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no SDK for Java for Office 365 API Preview. You could look at the Android SDK and try and use it with Java Web Application but I appreciate that may not be the easiest of tasks.
If this is something you are interested in I would highly recommend submitting this on UserVoice where our engineers are listening http://aka.ms/OfficeDevFeedback